# Help in this easy lemma about dimension in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm studying dimension of quasiprojective varieties which is defined as

$$\dim(X)=trdeg(k(X)|k)$$

if $X$ is a quasiprojective variety.

I didn't understood this lemma:

> If $f:X\to Y$ is a finite morphism between quasiprojective varieties ,
>   then $\dim(X)=dim(Y)$.
>
> **Proof**
>
> Since $f$ is finite, then the extension of fields $k(X)|k(Y)$ induced
>   by $f$ is algebraic. Thus, $k\subset k(Y)\subset K(X)$ and
>
> $$\dim (X)=trdeg(k(X)|k)=trdeg(K(Y)|k)=\dim(Y)))$$

Why does the extension of fields $k(X)|k(Y)$ is algebraic? What I know about finite morphisms is that $k[X]$ is integer over $k[Y]$, but I couldn't prove $k(X)|k(Y)$ is algebraic using this fact.

I didn't understand also why $trdeg(k(X)|k)=trdeg(k(Y)|k$. What I know is if $K(X)|K(Y)$ is algebraic, then we have $trdeg (k(X)|k(Y))=0$

I need help.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

Following the answer below concerning the first paragraph: If $f/g\in K(X)$ we have $f,g\in K[X]$, then there are positive integers $n,m$ and $h_i,h'_i\in K(Y)$ such that $f^n+f^{n-1}h_1+\ldots+h_n=0$  and $g^m+g^{m-1}h'_1+\ldots+h_m'=0$ Ok, I understood that, but I couldn't finish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$k[X]$ is integral over $k[Y]$ means that every element of $k[X]$ is the root of a monic polynomial over $k[Y]$. Forget about the monic and view $k[Y]$ in its field of fractions $k(Y)$: every element of $k[X]$ is algebraic over $k(Y)$. The same then holds for every element of $k(X)$ (as both denominator and numerator of an element of $k(X)$ are algebraic over $k(Y)$).

The fact that $\text{trdeg}(k(X)|k) = \text{trdeg}(k(Y)|k)$ then either follows from the general fact that $\text{trdeg}(K|L) + \text{trdeg}(L|k) = \text{trdeg}(K|k)$ or just directly form the definition.

Comment: Concerning the first paragraph: If $f/g\in K(X)$ we have $f,g\in K[X]$, then there are positive integers $n,m$ and $h_i,h'_i\in K(Y)$ such that $f^n+f^{n-1}h_1+\ldots+h_n=0$  and $g^m+g^{m-1}h'_1+\ldots+h_m'=0$ Ok, I understood that, but I couldn't finish the proof.

Concerning the second paragraph: I think we have a multiplication instead of a sum (see page 285 of this book http://books.google.com.br/books?id=hiQ8e0b48swC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user75086 It's a sum, not a product.  Your reference is about degree as a field extension, which is completely different from transcendence degree.  For example, $k(X)$ has transcendence degree $1$ over $k$, but $[k(X):k]$ is infinite.

Comment: @User-33433 I can't see the difference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree thanks

Comment: @user75086 Transcendence degree measures the maximum number of algebraically independent elements.  Field degree measures the maximum number of _linearly_ independent elements (equivalently, the dimension as a vector space).  For example, $\pi$ and $\frac{1}{\pi}$ are linearly independent, but not algebraically independent.  Another example: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$, but transcendence degree zero, since $(\sqrt{2})^2 - 2 = 0$, so $\sqrt{2}$ is linearly independent of $\mathbb{Q}$, but not algebraically independent.

Comment: @User-33433 Now I understand the difference, thank you very much, great explanation.

Comment: @User-33433 btw why $\pi$ and $\frac{1}{\pi}$ are not algebraically independent?

Comment: @user75086 Because $\pi \cdot \frac{1}{\pi} = 1$, which is a nontrivial algebraic relation between the two.

Comment: @User-33433 Of course, thanks again